# how to configure spring mvc 3 to use jaxb2 for xml MarshallingView inside ContentNegotiatingViewResolver?

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, jaxb

I know using mvc:annotation-driven will give me that for free. But I'd like to have more control of it.

my config is like the following:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="text/xml"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView" >
                    <property name="marshaller">
                            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                           <property name="contextPath" value="com.appservices.dtos"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Spring does not like the contextPath property, how to tell it to scan some package to find all jaxb beans? Thanks.

Comment: do you get any exception during your application context initialization? what spring version are you using? Also remember that the packages specified in the contextPath are separated with : and don't see sub-packages, i.e. the dto classes have to be in that same exact package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried with classesToBeBound property? In any case your problem has nothing to do with spring mvc or contentnegotiatingViewResolver, is with Jaxb2Marshaller

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Flight</value>
            <value>org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Flights</value>                
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schema" value="classpath:org/springframework/oxm/schema.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I knew that will work. But I just don't like to list all jaxb classes. And in that approach, you will have to create "collection" classes, i.e, you need to create "Flights" class for "Flight" class.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 3.1, new property "packagesToScan" is added in Jaxb2Marshaller which performs what you are expecting.  However there is still a bug prohibiting it from being works correctly, but you can expect next release will have that fix (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom class that scans all JAXB-annotated classes, due to Jarno Walgemoed:

http://springinpractice.com/2011/12/29/its-back-the-classpathscanningjaxb2marshaller/

I'm using it on a project and it works great.